# Select the same columns from a list of tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am looking to run this query on a list of tables.

```
SELECT Description,Code,count(*) as count
FROM table1
  group by Description,code
  having count(*) > 1
```

I will have to run this query on 30+ different tables, I was wondering If I could change the from statement and just list off the table names.

In addition, is there some functionality that will add the name of the table that it came from in a seperate column to distinguish where the results came from?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe ask yourself *why* you have 30 different tables!

Comment: ^^^^ All with the same data/columns in them. Sounds like a database design boob to me

Comment: Im a data analyst intern, Who am I to argue haha

Comment: Well maybe now is your chance to shine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use UNION ALL to put it together. Unless you need some dynamic table selection.

```
SELECT Description,Code,count(*) as count, 'table1' as tableNane
FROM table1
  group by Description,code
  having count(*) > 1

UNION ALL

SELECT Description,Code,count(*) as count, 'table2' as tableNane
FROM table2
  group by Description,code
  having count(*) > 1
...
```

Actualy I like @Shubhradeep Majumdar version. It will generate more concise code.

```
SELECT Description,Code, Count(Code), tableName FROM (
    SELECT Description,Code, 'table1' as tableName
    FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Description,Code, 'table2' as tableName
    FROM table2
) tables
GROUP BY tableName, Description, Code
   HAVING COUNT(Code) > 1
```

But there might be a little catch to it. It is more elegant code, but it might actually be slower than first version. The problem is that tableName is appended at every record before grouping while in my first version you do that on already processed data.

Answer (score 1):

Carrying over from @Marek's answer, You could first append all the tables to a table with `union all`.

```
select *, 'tab1' as tabnm from tab1
union all
select *, 'tab2' as tabnm from tab2
union all
select *, 'tab3' as tabnm from tab3
-- and so on...
```

And then use your code to process that final table.
will save you a great deal of time.

EDITED with a column specifying the table name

Comment: If I did that would there be a way to specify the table that it came from? When I union all of them I will lose track of where they came from

Comment: so you can add a column as "tab1" as name to each statement

Comment: Yes, you can stil keep track of tables this way. Just use `select *, 'tab1' as tableName from tab1` Like I did. But whether to use this version or mine will depend on how you want to group your data. Each table separate (my) or all tables together (Shubhradeep)

Comment: Yes, I updated my query to include that. Thanks, @MarekVitek.

Comment: @MarekVitek I have a concern about your code. You are running a `group by` on multiple tables and then appending them using `union all`. My concern is that, there might be some values that may miss the `group by` as they are present in two different tables, same value in tab1 and tab2 being rolled up. So the final appended table might not be have an distinct "description" column. You will need to run another query from your table with a `group by`. Do look into it. I think appending tables first will give you the exact essence.

Comment: @ShubhradeepMajumdar Yes, I am aware of that. I have mentioned it in my previous post that there is difference between our solutions. I was also working under assumptions that OP wants to group data from individual table and then combine it `... to distinguish where the results came from?` IMHO you wouldn't be able to get that without grouping on individual tables.